# How can I immerse a light bulb in water?

Tags: electrical, lighting

[image]

I have a transparent wine glass which I want to be filled with colored water and then place a light bulb immersed in the water so that when I switch on the bulb the wine glass emits the color of the water (If I fill it with blue color water I get blue light), is it possible in a very inexpensive way?

Comment: You understand that it's inherently dangerous to mix water and electricity, right?  As in - potentially fatal?

Comment: the wire is totally insulated, the current will never come in contact with the water

Comment: You mean that is the goal.  But since you're doing it yourself, and you don't know how to proceed, making this a "my first electrical" project is a great way to turn yourself into a corpse.  Have you considered colored light-bulbs instead?

Comment: The heat of the element will cause a temperature differential between the inside and the water cooled outside of the glass of the bulb, almost definitely  cracking it. Now you've got 120/240 v going through a short circuit.

Comment: I recommend not doing this at all. But, if you insist on playing with electricity and water, might I suggest flashlight bulbs/LEDs and batteries as a power source.

Comment: This is something you want to do with white LED's rather than regular incandescents; 5VDC rather than 120VAC. If really want the 'light bulb' shape, then drill out the bottom of a bulb, and insert the LED thru the hole. See: http://www.instructables.com/id/LEDs-for-Beginners/

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, you mean is it possible using LED?

Comment: Sure. You want to keep the voltage low so you don't run an electrocution risk. Also you want all the wiring encased in clear plastic to keep it dry, and eliminate the possibility of electrolysis, which'd cloud up your water and destroy your circuit. Project is entirely doable, just not trivial. If you go ahead, mes with some LED's on dry land first, so you understand them. Electrolysis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, thanks, my goal was to light up the water anyhow so that the entire room is filled with colored light, I am not sure if I will go ahead with this, but nice to know that it is possible :)

Comment: Closing because I think this counts as a hobby project and unlikely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [mineral oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer_oil) instead of water, since mineral oil is not conductive.  Mineral oil is actually used in some transformers and other electrical devices, to provide insulation, cooling, and other functions.  There is a popular YouTube video, where a [computer is submerged in mineral oil](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtufuXLvOok).

I'm not sure if you'd be able to dye the mineral oil, but you could certainly use colored lights to achieve the affect. [Popular Science](http://www.popsci.com/) has an article about making [Liquid Lamps](http://www.popsci.com/bubblelight), that you might find interesting.